# Cannot read property 'ObjectID' of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, openshift, mongodb-rest

I am forking / try to understand [mongodb-rest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb-rest) project. When I am running only the `rest.js` script I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'ObjectID' of undefined
    at app.post.connection.connect.res.status.json.message (/var/lib/openshift/5556b4c4fcf9336abf0000de/app-root/runtime/repo/server.js:99:32)
```

at this line, when I try to handle `PUT` message:

```
var spec = {'_id': new BSON.ObjectID(req.params.id)};
```

I have the same 'include' lines as `rest.js`

```
  var mongodb = require("mongodb");
  var BSON = mongodb.BSONPure;
```

but running on `OpenShift` servers.

Any idea what is wrong?

## UPDATE

I tried to use same package:

```
  var bson = require("bson");
  var BSON = bson.BSONPure.BSON;
  //var BSON = mongodb.BSONPure;
```

got same error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using the **[bson](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bson)** package instead of mongodb:

```
var BSON = require('bson').BSONPure
```